# Cisco 3560-X and Bind9 DDNS integration

Tags: cisco, bind, switch, ddns

Experts,

In an infrastructure I'm currently working on, we have one Cisco 3560-X as a core switch and an internal Bind9 DNS server. The 3560 is acting as the DHCP server. BIND9 currently has names of the internal linux servers.

There are about 80-100 client desktops and about 200 other devices which uses static IP for now. I intend to use DDNS here which should enable me to connect any client using host name. I can't get a real documentation on how to get this working.

I saw it's easy by using ISC-DHCP on a linux machine however, I prefer to use the 3560 DHCP Server.

Please advice, how can I push hostname/ip to BIND9 from cisco 3560, if at all it's possible.

Thanks !

Comment: Is there a technical reason to keep the 3560 as your DHCP server?  You can always configure an ip helper address on any vlan where DHCP is required and provide centralized DHCP with DNS integration.

Comment: There is no technical reason, just a preference. Seems like it can't be done using the switch alone. Anyway, I'm almost convinced on using a Debian+isc-dhcp+bind9 setting and do ip helper address approach.

Comment: Apparently you can use IOS DHCP to update a dynamic DNS. I've never done it so I can't offer much help, but here's the link I found: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dns/configuration/12-4/dns-12-4-book/dns-dyn-dns-supp-ios.html